# Add line breaks that respect spaces and not cutting off words

Tags: formula

Is there an easy and clean way to add a linebreak in that respects spaces (characters) and also character limits (without cutting the word off?)

Here is my formula today:

```
TRIM(LEFT(TextArea__c, 75))& BR() & TRIM(MID(TextArea__c, 76, 75))+ "..."
```

Is there a way to keep the words whole when enacting a linebreak?

Comment: Realistically... No. You can kind of do it with FIND, MID, LEFT, SUBSTRING, etc, but it gets really messy quickly. Also, I suspect you're trying to solve a different underlying problem in a particularly hard way. Perhaps you should try asking about the underlying problem instead. See http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, I figured it out.